# How to idiomatically check if a variable "is falsey" or "not true" in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I am writing a query in Phoenix and I am needing to check where a field is `falsey`.

for example `where(query, [x], x is not true)`

And to my surprise there is not much information out there on how to idiomatically check for `falsey` or `not true` in elixir.

Just for more clarity some psuedocode:

```
iex(1)> x = nil or x = false
iex(2)> x is not true #desired idiomatic expression
> true
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're going for here but this may help: https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am writing a query in Phoenix

There is no such thing as “query in *Phoenix*” in the first place. Queries [in this context] are all about talking to a database and *Phoenix* basically could not care less about the database. One might have a perfect *Phoenix* project that has no database behind.

What you are querying is [`Ecto`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto), using [`Ecto.Query`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html).

> for example `where(query, [x], x is not true)`

Talking about the database, such a query makes a little sense. Databases naturally have no notion of `falsey`, they distinguish `false` and `NULL` and even SQL syntax yells at as saying that. For finding `false` one should do:

```sql
WHERE x = FALSE -- or WHERE x = 0
```

and for finding `NULL`s

```sql
WHERE x IS NULL
```

That said, if you find yourself looking up for *neither FALSE nor NULL* in the database, you have issues with your database design, that definitely will bite you later.

---

OTOH, in Elixir itself the question is perfectly valid. We have two `falsey` terms: atoms `false` and `nil`. Everything else considered to be a `truthy` value.

To check for it, one should use [`Kernel.!/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#!/1)

```rb
if !x, do: IO.puts("#{x.inspect} is truthy")
```

Comment: I should have reprased the question about querying in phoenix haha, it was meant more to just give context where i was seeking use the conditional. But thank you though this gives a lot of help to my understanding of designing db's.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
x = false

if x do
  "truthy"
else 
  "falsey"
end

=> "falsey"
```

This would return `"falsey"` if `x = nil` too. Everything else would return `"truthy"`

Shorthand: `if x, do: "truthy", else: "falsey"`